# Discord.js Embed Random Image

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I've been trying to get my discord bot to pick a random image for this embed I'm trying to create but I just can't figure it out

```
var images = ["Image1", "Image2", "Image3", "Image4" ];
var image = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

if (command === `randompic`) {    
    let random = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Here is your random pic')
    .setAuthor('mortis')
    .setImage(+images[image])

    message.channel.send(random);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?
(I'm a complete beginner when it comes to javascript so cut me some slack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these `ImageN` placeholders are links to images, use this

```
var images = ["Image1", "Image2", "Image3", "Image4" ];
var image = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

if (command === `randompic`) {    
    let random = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('Here is your random pic')
      .setAuthor('mortis')
      .setImage(String([images[image]]))

    message.channel.send(random);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the image variable is just the index, so I suggest either renaming image to index and then change it to `setImage(images[index])` or revaluing image to `images[Math.floor(Math.random * images.length)]`, this way you can just do `setImage(image)`

I'm not sure why the other commenter did `String([images[image]])`, don't need it here

```js
const images = ["Image1", "Image2", "Image3", "Image4" ];
const image = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];

if (command === `randompic`) {    
    const random = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('Here is your random pic')
      .setAuthor('mortis')
      .setImage(image)

    message.channel.send(random);
}
```